# python 2: converting string variable to a format compatible with sql string in arcpy

Tags: python-2.7, arcpy

I am still pretty basic when it comes to coding. I am working on a project that will be helpful for me on a daily basis and will help me to learn python better. I have been looking for a solution to a problem but have not found one that works yet. And just a note in advance, I have been given feedback regarding using python 3 but the server at work that has arcmap on it uses python 2 so that is why I have been using 2. I am also woking on learning 3 at the same time :)

I am using an arcmap tool that uses an SQL query to select the features from a shapefile that will be used to create a new Featureclass. My problem is that I cannot get the values in one of my variables into the proper format --> ('value','value','value') to be used in the SQL query.
I often type in many values and do not want to type in the single quotes and commas myself and there is no where to copy and paste them from, so I want to just type the values with a space and have the script do the rest.

I am assigning the sql code into a variable for easy input into my tool. The sql query should look like this (I have input some values where the variables will go so you can see what arcmap wants to see. FOREST_FILE_ID and ROAD_SECTION_ID are column names being queried):

"FOREST_FILE_ID = 'RoadName' AND ROAD_SECTION_ID IN ('A','B'.'C','D')"

I have tried split() and join() but nothing has worked exactly as required.
This is a coles notes version of my most recent code attempt along with the output at the end:

```
roadName = raw_input("Please enter the road name. >> ")
secNo = (raw_input("Please enter the road section(s) >> ").upper()).split(', ')
roadQuery = "FOREST_FILE_ID = '{}'  AND  ROAD_SECTION_ID IN ({})".format(fileNo, secNo)
print(roadQuery)
```

the output I get is:

> What is the permit number? >> roadName
>
> Please enter the road section(s) >> a b c D
>
> FOREST_FILE_ID = 'roadName'  AND  ROAD_SECTION_ID IN (['A B C D'])

as you can see this is not in the required format ('A','B','C','D'). I am not sure how go about creating the format I require in my variable. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that seems to work. It i not elegant but my sql works. so that is good.

```
import os, re
from os import path

fileNo = raw_input("What is the permit number? >> ").upper()
secNo = (raw_input("Please enter the road section(s) >> ").upper())#.split(', ')
secNo = re.sub(" ", "','",secNo)
roadQuery = "FOREST_FILE_ID = '{}'  AND  ROAD_SECTION_ID IN ('{}')".format(fileNo, secNo)
print(roadQuery)
```